# Why are the margin settings not acting properly on my website?

Tags: css, margin

All of the margin settings for the content within the main body section of the homepage of this site I'm working on are not displaying properly and they are overlapping one another. This has been causing me a crap-load of annoyance and I can't figure out what's wrong. Please take a look and see if you can help me.

once again, there are 3 sections within the main body and they are all showing up wrong!

Here's my site:

http://studentweb.eku.edu/alamaldean_alami/d+m/index.html

The first problem is that from the first section (history) to the second (buttons) there is an extra gap of 20px in addition to the margin that I have set, why is there a random gap (firebug and google's 'inspect element' both do not show anything there, just a random extra space).

The second problem is that the 'button' section should have a 20px margin between it and the 'content-area' section since 'content-area' is set to have a margin of 20px.

The final problem is that the bottom margin between the 'content-area' section and the footer should be a total of 40px because both of those each have a margin of 20px.

[image]

Comment: This is too vague. You need to either explain in more details, or include screenshots and red-mark the problems.

Comment: There I added a screenshot with a visual explanation of my issue.

Comment: Dear what exactly you want? you are confusing bit.... by seeing your screen shot i m getting confused, can you please explain in detail.. please. remove position:relative is correct.

Comment: I updated the website after fixing `position:relative` as you can see, there is no change.

Comment: Please see my answer and follow and let me know what is remaining...

Comment: I followed some of your answer, most of my issue I figured out before you posted it, and some of your answer just hapened to not be exactly what I wanted to do, but I even made some aditional changes to my own code to improve it. Its all fixed now. Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below css from .buttons class line 194 style.css

```
position:relative;
```

Add this css on home.css line 3

```
.history {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 20px 20px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Add this on style.css line 108

```
.footer {
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
}
```

style.css line 102

```
.content-area {
    background: url("..//images/transbackc.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

home.css line 38

```
.services div {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Final output of above css see below image:

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you, the problem was that I had conflicting CSS classes '.buttons' I forgot about the ones in styles.css hich was for a form on a different page.  Thanks so much for pointing this out to me even though you probably didn't realize that that's what you did haha, I changed the class names it and it fixed the problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `position: relative` from your .buttons class

Comment: Just now tried that, it didn't work, thanks for trying at least.

Comment: did you remove it from the .buttons class or the .button class? I just went to your site and removed it from **.buttons** class with developer tools and it fixes the problem.

Comment: also, it's on style.css that position: relative is in.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that problem. I had conflicting classes. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please check it as answer.